# mongodb: issues using $lte and $gte

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

look at this bizarre result:

```
list(db.users.find({"produit_up.spec.prix":{"$gte":0, "$lte": 1000}}, {"_id":0,"produit_up":1})) 
Out[5]: 
[{u'produit_up': [{u'avatar': {u'avctype': u'image/jpeg', 
 u'orientation': u'portrait', 
 u'photo': ObjectId('506867863a5f3a0ea84dcd6c')}, 
u'spec': {u'abus': 0, 
 u'date': u'2012-09-30', 
 u'description': u"portable tr\xe8s solide, peu servi, avec batterie d'une autonomie de 3 heures.", 
 u'id': u'alucaard134901952647', 
 u'namep': u'nokia 3310', 
 u'nombre': 1, 
 u'prix': 1000, 
 u'tags': [u'portable', u'nokia', u'3310'], 
 u'vendu': False}}, 
{u'avatar': {u'avctype': u'image/jpeg', 
 u'orientation': u'portrait', 
 u'photo': ObjectId('50686d013a5f3a04a8923b3e')}, 
 u'spec': {u'abus': 0, 
 u'date': u'2012-09-30', 
 u'description': u'\u0646\u0628\u064a\u0639 \u0623\u064a \u0641\u0648\u0646 \u062c\u062f\u064a\u062f \u0641\u064a  \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0648\u0627\u0637 \u0645\u0639\u0627\u0647 \u0634\u0627\u0631\u062c\u0648\u0631 \u062f\u0648\u0631\u064a\u062c \u064a\u0646', 
 u'id': u'alucaard134902092967', 
 u'namep': u'iphone 3gs', 
 u'nombre': 1, 
 u'prix': 20000, 
 u'tags': [u'iphone', u'3gs', u'apple'], 
 u'vendu': False}}, 
{u'avatar': {u'avctype': u'image/jpeg', 
 u'orientation': u'paysage', 
 u'photo': ObjectId('50686d3e3a5f3a04a8923b40')}, 
u'spec': {u'abus': 0, 
 u'date': u'2012-09-30', 
 u'description': u'vends 206 toutes options 2006 hdi.', 
 u'id': u'alucaard134902099082', 
 u'namep': u'peugeot 206', 
 u'nombre': 1, 
 u'prix': 500000, 
 u'tags': [u'voiture', u'206', u'hdi'], 
 u'vendu': False}}]}] 

list(db.users.find({"produit_up.spec.prix":{"$gte":0, "$lte": 100}}, {"_id":0,"produit_up":1})) 

Out[6]: [] 

pymongo.version 

Out[8]: '2.3+'
```

and it gives me the same result in Mongo Shell:

```
db.version() 
2.2.0
```

Comment: https://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/9cfb62609de046ee?hl=fr

Comment: Did you solve this problem then? Looks by the thread there that you did

Comment: sorry, i just received the answer in google groups, i'll mark the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the answer from Bernie Hackett

> You have three values for "produit_up.spec.prix", 1000, 20000, 500000. 
>   Why would you think that {"$gte":0, "$lte": 100} would match any of 
>   those values? 100 is less than all of those values. 
>   The reason that {"$gte":0, "$lte": 1000} returns all three documents 
>   is that they are all subdocuments in an array. Since one of the 
>   subdocuments in the array is matched **the entire enclosing document** 
>   is a match for your query. Since you did a projection on only 
>   "produit_up", just that array (including all array members) is 
>   returned. Use $elemMatch in MongoDB 2.2 to only return the exact 
>   matching array element. 
>   MongoDB and PyMongo are working as designed here.
>
> To get the behavior I think you're asking for see the $elemMatch operator: 
>   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/elemMatch/